# Slick carousel - Want center slider bigger than others

Tags: javascript, jquery

Slick plugin is great for carousels & testimonials. I am trying to use the center mode attribute of the slick carousel plugin. On their website the center mode (centerMode:true) shows the active slide to be bigger than the rest. But that is not happening!  This is the slick sites url: [http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IhhD.png)

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Youg Desai</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/slick/slick.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/slick/slick-theme.css">
  </head>
  <style>

  .slick-center .slide-h3{
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .slider{
    width: 600px;  
    height:150px;
    margin: 20px auto;    
    text-align: center;
  }
  .slide-h3{
    margin: 10% 0 10% 0;
    padding: 40% 20%;
    background: #008ed6;
  }
  .slider div{
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .slick-slide{
    opacity: .6;
  }
  .slick-center{
    display: block;
    max-width: 10% !important;
    max-height:20% !important;
    opacity: 1;


  }
  </style>
  <body>
  <section id="slick-content">

  <div class="slider">
    <div><div class="slide-h3">1</div></div>
    <div><div class="slide-h3">2</div></div>
    <div><div class="slide-h3">3</div></div>
    <div><div class="slide-h3">4</div></div>
    <div><div class="slide-h3">5</div></div>
    <div><div class="slide-h3">6</div></div>

  </div>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick/slick.js"></script>





  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  speed:1500,
  index: 2,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link behind `http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/` is an image which I don't know if it is relevant to your question. Either way, please [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42000555/edit) your question and update the link with the right link address

Answer (score 18):

Finally found the answer on stack-overflow itself!
Posting it here so that people seeing this question don't have to search it.

```
.slick-center {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

The above will make the center slider bigger. You may  have to adjust the padding though.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the following to `.slick-list` (generated when you run `$('.your-class').slick({ ... });`) in order to see the newly scaled-up `.slick-center` in full (props to Ashique Desai for the scale tip):

```
.slick-center {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);    
}

.slick-list { 
  padding:45px 60px !important;
  margin-left:30px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **width** instead of **transform**. You usually end up with slides to jump. That was the main issue with this "technique". However it is better than transform scale, and more flexible for me at least.

To **fix slides not aligning correctly** because of the calculations, add this:

```
.slick-track {
    width: fit-content !important;
}
```